# Why is my span tag click not working for jQuery ?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
  <li class="resultsTitle left"><span>Total Results&nbsp;</span><span id="totalResults" class="bold">@totals.TotalResults.ToString("N0")</span></li>
<li class="resultsTitle left"><span>Company Results&nbsp;</span><span id="companyResults" class="bold">@totals.CompanyCount.ToString("N0")</span></li>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#companyResults").click(function () {
        alert('hello world');
    });

    $("#totalResults").click(function () {
        alert('hello world');
    });
});
```

We tried a couple of things to capture click event. Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: are you capture some exception?, because for me your code look's good

Comment: Do you have any js error on the page?

Comment: debug... try using firebug or make some alerts....

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/kfvgP/ Did you remember to include your JQuery framework?

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me here

http://jsfiddle.net/uhgZg/

Verify that you have jQuery included in your layout page correctly or in your view

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And verify that this code is in a script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#companyResults").click(function () {
            alert('hello world');
        });

        $("#totalResults").click(function () {
            alert('hello world');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code fires perfectly when these things are in place

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the 2 options I see in relation to this issue

- Your ids `#companyResults` and `#totalResults` are not unique, this would cause  troubles. If this the case, you could use css classes to select elements instead of ids.
- You have an js error on your page preventing the click event handler to run properly. You could easily detect this using firebug or chrome developer tools

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1. Add `alert(jQuery().jquery);` to your Javascript to verify jQuery is being loaded properly. You should see an alert with your jQuery version number if so.
2. It's hard to tell if this is likely without seeing how you're styling the markup, but perhaps you're testing your code by clicking on the "Total Results" instead of the bold value that you're outputting? The Javascript as written only registers the click handler on the `@totals.etc...` output.